# Start a Python script in a shell with SSH

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I want to start a Python script with `paramiko` which connects to my raspberry which acts as a server. Then after the connection to the raspberry it starts a script like this(to send data to an Arduino from another pc):

```
import tty
import sys
import termios
import serial
import os

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0' , 9600)

x = "./mjpg_streamer -i \"./input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -y\" -o \"./output_http.so -w ./www\""
os.system(x)


orig_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)

tty.setraw(sys.stdin)
x = 0
while x != chr(27): # ESC
    x=sys.stdin.read(1)[0]
    arduino.write(x)
termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, orig_settings)
```

This code works okay, kind of a raw_input just to simplify.

I want to connect automatically to the raspberry by ssh, and start a Python script that will ask for an input -which in the code above is a constant-.
I thought something like opening a new shell with the script above already indicated or something like that...

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer, there is not any options that could help you insert password into ssh command. You have to set up a share key-pair to use ssh without password prompt. Searching on the internet can give you ton of answers, for example: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id

So at first, set up key-pairs. Then use normal ssh to check whether it was successful. Then finally, in your python script, add some codes to deal with ssh.